# Shopware links builder doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, shopware

I have shopware cms version 5.2.22. After rebuild seo url index some links are still wrong. The most of links has look like http://site.dev/product but some of them are wrong, like http://site.dev/detail/index/sArticle/4551. Does somebody know how to fix it ? I have tried different ways, clear cache, truncate urls table...

Answer (score -1):

The problem was because some products existed with the same path in the table "s_core_rewrite_urls"